# Detect Empty result in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ActionResult` which return `PartialView()` or `new EmptyResult()`, How to detect in JS callback function if returned `data` is `EmptyResullt()`? I have tried many ways, i.e. compare with `null` or with `undefined` but no results. `console.log(data)` shows blank space. Any tips and tricks? :)

"more code":

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Checkif(int d)
    {
        if (d == 2) return new EmptyResult();
        else return PartialView();
    }
```

Js function:

```
function sth ()
{
    $.get('/home/Checkif/', {d: 2}, function(data){
        if(data === null) //<---- this does not work
        {
            //then sth;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please share more code

Comment: You need to know the data type of `data` in order to check whether it is empty or not. Does it come back as an object? an array? a string? Try `console.log(data)`

Comment: So what is EmptyResult() returning, my guess it is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, checking for `if (data) { // do something }` will work.

To specifically check for empty string, using `data === ''` should work.

Comment: Yeah, if(data) works perfectly! Spent much time to find solution and I did not achieve positive results. Thanks you! :)